# std:: insert iterator for unordered sets (or maps)?

Tags: c++, unordered-set, invalidation, insert-iterator

Is there an insert iterator in `std::` for unordered sets? As far as I can see, `std::inserter` requires an iterator argument. This is unsafe for unordered containers (at least for `boost::unordered_set`), because they may reallocate during an `insert` operation and render the passed `.begin()` iterator invalid.

So currently I have to pass my own iterator which essentially is an `boost::function_output_iterator` with a functor that simply calls `unorderedSet.insert(param1)`.

Why is it that `std::inserter` even *requires* the `hint` iterator argument anyway?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't. The reason that the `hint` argument is required is that `std::inserter` is meant for containers where *position* is required in the context of insertion. As you know, this is not the case for unordered containers.

`vector` in an example of a container where knowing `position` is a requirement for insertion. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert):

> ```
> (1)
> iterator insert( iterator pos, const T& value ); // (until C++11)
> iterator insert( const_iterator pos, const T& value ); // (since C++11)
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>  (2)
> iterator insert( const_iterator pos, T&& value ); // (since C++11)
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> (3)     
> void insert( iterator pos, size_type count, const T& value ); // (until C++11)
> iterator insert( const_iterator pos, size_type count, const T& value ); // (since C++11)
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> (4)     
> template< class InputIt >
> void insert( iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last); // (until C++11)
> template< class InputIt >
> iterator insert( const_iterator pos, InputIt first, InputIt last ); // (since C++11)
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> (5)
> iterator insert( const_iterator pos, std::initializer_list<T> ilist ); // (since C++11)
> ```
>
> Inserts elements at the specified location in the container.
>
> 1-2) inserts value **before pos**
>     3) inserts count copies of the value **before pos**
>     4) inserts elements from range [first, last) **before pos**.
>          This overload has the same effect as overload (3) if InputIt is an integral type.  <sup>(until C++11)</sup>
>          This overload only participates in overload resolution if InputIt qualifies as LegacyInputIterator, to avoid ambiguity with the overload (3).  <sup>(since C++11)</sup>
>   The behavior is undefined if first and last are iterators into *this.
>     5) inserts elements from initializer list ilist **before pos**.

---

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but rolling out your own is easy enough, if not a bit verbose:

```
template<typename Container>
class unordered_inserter {
public:
    using iterator_category = std::output_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = void;
    using reference_type = void;
    using difference_type = void;
    using pointer = void;
    using reference = void;
    using container_type = Container;

    unordered_inserter& operator++() {return *this;} //no-op
    unordered_inserter& operator++(int) {return *this;} //no-op
    unordered_inserter& operator*() {return *this;} //no-op
    constexpr unordered_inserter& operator=(const typename Container::value_type& value) {
        container->insert(value);
        return *this;
    }
    constexpr unordered_inserter& operator=(typename Container::value_type&& value) {
        container->insert(std::move(value));
        return *this;
    }
    unordered_inserter(Container* container)
        :    container(container)
    {}
protected:
    Container* container;
};
```

This probably can be refactored to support other kinds of insertion, but I think this is enough for now.

Here's me playing a bit with it:

```
int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> m;
    std::istringstream iss("1 2 3 4 5 6");

    std::transform(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), std::istream_iterator<int>(), unordered_inserter(&m), [](int v) {
        return decltype(m)::value_type{v, v*v};
    });
    std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"), [](auto pair) {
        return std::to_string(pair.first) + "," + std::to_string(pair.second);
    });
}
```

### [Live on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qetWca)

---

A thing to note here is that your assertion that passing this `hint` argument to unordered containers is unsafe is wrong. When `operator=` is called, and a new element is inserted into the container, the `iter` member is updated to whatever `insert` returns. Since this value is required to be valid, there's no way that `iter` can ever be invalidated.